# I cannot use the Highfrequency package with Jupyter notebook whereas in R studio I can

Tags: r, package, namespaces

I'm new in code. I need to use the "highfrequency" package but I can't. I tried several options that I found on internet but nothing worked for me.

I can download the package in Jupyter notebook but I cannot load it to use it ( please see below ).
Does anyone have had the same issue ?

I'm using Jupyter notebook with anaconda as IDE. I tried to use the highfrequency package into R studio and it worked, but I cannot use it in Jupyter.

Thank you for your help [image]

Comment: What version of R does your Jupyter Notebook see compared to your RStudio?

Comment: On jupyter  it's 3.6.1 and in R studio it's 4.1.2. I don't think it comes from that, because I can use other packages with the same red message. I think it comes from "fifelse is not exported by namespace:data.table. But I didn't find how to solve it. In case of it's due to my R version, how do you install a recent version of R in anaconda ? The most recent one that anaconda provides is 3.6.1

Comment: I think it is in part, or not helping in sorting the issue at least, the version because your R is 3.6.1 in Jupyter; however, it's trying to install something built with 3.6.3? Plus, it is totally comparing apples and oranges to compare Jupyter to RStudio in this case. If you had the same version of R on both, that would be different. So that belies the title of your post largely.

Comment: You should be able to get at least R 4.0.5 from Anaconda, see [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base). And if you go [here], and press `launch binder`, you'll see version 4.0.5 is installed and that is using conda via [this configuration file](https://github.com/fomightez/chapter7/blob/master/binder/environment.yml). If you launch it and then switch the interface by editing the URL once RStudio opens by changing the `rstudio` part of the URL to `lab`, you can see the same R is used by Jupyter there. So I think it is certainly possible to use newer R in Jupyter via Anaconda.

Comment: See [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/77335/anconda-r-version-how-to-upgrade-to-4-0-and-later) and [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/r-base) to try and get 4.1.3 in your system.

Comment: And just FYI, if you launch binder and switch to JupyterLab how I described and then open from the launcher a notebook with R backed kernel with R 4.0.5, you'll see `install.packages("highfrequency")` followed by `library(highfrequency)` works there. The install in the notebook talks quite a few minutes, but I just tried it.